Prove $d/dt\langle L\rangle=\langle N\rangle$ without computing over a specific basis
In Griffith 3rd Edition, Problem 4.23 asks for the proof of
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\langle\mathbf{L}\rangle=\langle\mathbf{r}\times-\nabla V\rangle=\langle\mathbf{N}\rangle$$
One evaluates $[\mathbf{L},H]$ and then uses the Ehrenfest's Theorem. For the commutator,
$$[\mathbf{L},H]=[r\times p,p^2/2m]+[r\times p,V]=\left[r\times-i\hbar\nabla,-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\right]+[r\times-i\hbar\nabla,V]$$
Is there a way to continue without expressing $\nabla$ over Cartesian basis, i.e. without using $$\nabla=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^T~?$$ The result is independent of any bases, so I believe the commutator can be evaluated without choosing a basis.

What does $N$ denote?

@TobiasFünke Torque $dL/dt$
